# Russia Characters randomly getting replaced as diamond with a question mark ��

Tags: content-delivery, dd4t

While rendering Russia content randomly we are getting diamond with a question mark ��.

we have enabled the below encoding in meta tags

УЗИ голов��ого мозга (нейросонография) – выявляет пороки развития головного мозга, измеряет внутричерепное давление и скорость кровотока в полушариях

If you observe головного this word repeated in the sentence twice, first "н" character is having issue, rest the data is coming fine.

We enabled globalization in web.config with UTF-8 that also didn't resolved the issue.

Can you please help us resolving the encoding issue without disabling rewrite module.

Options we tried are below.

1. Meta data charset set to UTF-8
2. Replacing characters with ASCII equivalent.
3. Enabling Globalization with UTF-8 encoding
4. Database fields are UTF-8 Encoded, In DB there is no issue

The issue is happening while rendering in the page view.

Thanks,

Prasanna

Comment: A very similar question (same word giving issues) has been asked and answered here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14515/junk-characters-displaying-on-webpage. Perhaps you could explore those options first?

Comment: How( What Form) is the data present in DB ? Can you give a screenshot of data present in DB ? depending on that you may need to HTML Decode/Encode the data on rendering.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate @TannerBrine. I agree, and I've flagged this one for closure on that basis.