# Special Encoding Charactor issue in website

Tags: 2011, 2013

I am facing the special char issue where copyright symbol is not displaying correctly in website

attached error snapshot.

using below in HTML page

in rich text field even if I use © then also not working

using rich text field schema[image]

Comment: It’s looks like more of content type issue it should be UTF-8 charset.

Comment: This question already has an answer, so I'm flagging it as a duplicate. https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/14515/129

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Junk Characters displaying on webpage](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14515/junk-characters-displaying-on-webpage)

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the Elena Serghie [blog](http://elenaserghie.blogspot.ie/2012/01/7-clues-to-solve-character-encoding.html) post to run through the highlighted 7 checkpoints to fix the encoding issue.